# Track OAuth 2 provider on client page

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have the ability to login via Facebook and Google on my website. This is done using OAuth2.

I use the same redirect URL whether the user is returning from facebook or google, and pass through the provider name in the state field. Is this the recommended way to track the provider? Otherwise I do not know who to validate the token with if I do not know which provider the token comes from.

Are there other preferred methods for accomplishing this?

Comment: I'd use slightly different URLs. Even a query string parameter would do.

Comment: So my redirectURL can contain a query string parameter?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it?

Comment: I just assumed it couldn't because I didn't see anything saying it could. Makes sense, I'll give that a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `state` parameter should be an opaque value that cannot be guessed by an attacker since it is not protected from modifications. If you need to track state, you should **refer** to it by using the `state` parameter but that parameter itself should be randomized and/or encrypted. Storing the provider identifier in plaintext in the `state` parameter is not safe. Users could modify the `state` parameter themselves or attackers could craft an authorization request with a `state` value that they choose.

The way to track the provider is by storing it in the backend session state and generate a reference to that session/state that you pass in the `state` parameter. To prevent cross-site request forgery you should also keep some encrypted/randomized cookie that binds the state to the browser. This is described in more detail: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12

Addendum:

One of the problems with using OAuth 2.0 + provider specific extensions for login is exactly this: you cannot establish the provider and user identity in a way that works for all providers in a uniform and generic way. In your case you'll already have to know the provider before you can perform a sensible interaction with it. Enter OpenID Connect: it is a extension profile of OAuth 2.0 that gives you login semantics in a standardized way. It would give you a verifiable JSON object (JWT) with standardized values that tell you who the provider is (`iss`) and who the user is (`sub`).

Google signin already has migrated already to OpenID Connect, as has Microsoft and others like Salesforce, hopefully Facebook will follow.